Modify record of array type and return function as table
I have column video with type array text.
Example the current input data like this
video = [one.mp4, two.mp4]
Then i want add url of every each item, like this
video = [www.google.com/one.mp4, www.google.com/two.mp4]
After replace the data of old array with new array, i want the function return as a table. I have done like below, but many error appears.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION read_posts () 
RETURNS TABLE (
  id bigint, 
  video text[], 
  caption text, 
) AS $$
DECLARE
  var_query_post public.posts%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT
    post.id,
    post.video,
    post.caption,
    profile.id,
    profile.full_name,
  INTO var_query_post
  FROM public.posts AS post
  LEFT JOIN public.profiles AS profile
    ON post.user_id = profile.id
  ORDER BY post.id DESC;

  FOR i IN 0..ARRAY_LENGTH(var_query_post.video) LOOP
    var_query_post.video := ARRAY_REPLACE(var_query_post.video, var_query_post.video[i], 
                            CONCAT('haha', 'hoho'));
    i := i + 1;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN NEXT var_query_post;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


Not sure if this is correct, but I don't think you have to write a function or a loop:
demo at db<>fiddle
SELECT id
     , ARRAY_AGG(CONCAT('www.google.com/', uv)) AS video
     , caption
FROM public.posts
   , UNNEST(video) AS uv
GROUP BY id, caption
ORDER BY id;




id
video
caption




1
{www.google.com/one.mp4,www.google.com/two.mp4}
caption1


2
{www.google.com/three.mp4,www.google.com/four.mp4}
caption2




can you combine it with LEFT JOIN please? i already update the question code. Because error appear when i try combine it

here i create new question https://stackoverflow.com/q/78773041/9597017
