Joined table where unnest array in from clause and array_agg in select clause, but return empty data
Continue from my previous question
Link Previous Question Stackoverflow
I have column video with type array text.
Example the current input data like this
video = [one.mp4, two.mp4]
Then i want add url of every each item, like this
video = [www.google.com/one.mp4, www.google.com/two.mp4]
Below is my code now but return empty data
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION read_posts () 
RETURNS TABLE (
  id bigint,
  video text[], 
  caption text, 

  -- profile
  profile json

) AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
  SELECT
    post.id,
    ARRAY_AGG(CONCAT('www.google.com', v)) AS video,
    post.caption,
   
    -- profile
    JSON_BUILD_OBJECT (
      'id', profile.id,
      'full_name', profile.full_name,
    )
  FROM public.posts AS post
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL UNNEST(post.video) AS v
  LEFT JOIN public.profiles AS profile
    ON post.user_id = profile.id
  GROUP BY post.id, profile.id
  ORDER BY post.id DESC;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


Please review [mre]: this post lacks table DDL, sample data, and expected output. There is insufficient information to determine why data isn't being returned. Why are you creating a function instead of a view (or even a direct query)?
